# Setting float field in operator<< function for output and then changing it back

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

Let's say I have some class, Merchandise, with a field called price. When someone tries to output my Merchandise object, most commonly with cout, I want to display the dollar amount that the item sells for, with exactly two decimal places. But what I don't want to do is permanently change the stream. For example, if someone does this:

```
double someNumber;  //someNumber should be displayed to 3 decimal places
Merchandise product;
/* something happens to product here */

cout << product << "And the number generated is " << someNumber << endl;
```

In this case, product should be displayed with two decimal places, but someNumber should still be displayed with 3, like the client was expecting to happen. So I don't want to change the ostream permanently when I implement my function, I just want to display 2 decimal places for this one field, and then return it back to normal. How do I do this?

I tried changing the ostream flags once and then changing them back like so:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Merchandise& rhs) {
  int precision = os.precision();  //Get the current precision so we can change it back later
  /* I don't know how to get the current floatfield */
  os.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);  //Forces the same precision all the time
  os.precision(2);  //Forces a precision of 2

  os << rhs.price;

  os.precision(precision);
  /* I can't change the floatfield back, since I don't know how to get it or what kind of object to store it in */ 

  return os;
}
```

I'm just figuring this out as I go along. I don't know whether this is the best or standard method for doing this or not. If there's a better way to do it, can someone let me know? If not, then how do I get the current floatfield to store in a variable, and what kind of object do I use to store it in? Thanks.

Comment: Because of rounding errors, you should consider using an integer to store the price (fixed point). For example, "1995" for $19.95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precision()` also returns the old precision when setting the new precision, so you can take advantage of that and set the precision inline with the assignment:

```c++
std::streamsize precision = os.precision(2);
```

`std::streamsize` is the same as `int` for narrow-character streams (streams that use `char`) but for best practice you should that type.

Moreover, to hold the flags, you should store the stream's flags in an object of type `std::ios_base::fmtflags`:

```c++
std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = os.flags(os.flags() | std::ios_base::fixed);
```

Then simply change it back when done.

---

You can facilitate this by using a RAII technique to change the settings back when done:

```c++
template <typename Stream>
class format_saver
{
public:
    format_saver(Stream& os)
        : os_(os)
        , flags(os.flags())
        , precision(os.precision())
    { }

    ~format_saver() { os_.flags(flags); os_.precision(precision); }
private:
    Stream& os_;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flags;
    std::streamsize         precision;
};
```

Now you can do:

```c++
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Merchandise& rhs)
{
    format_saver<std::ostream> _(os);
    return os << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << rhs.price;
}
```

Comment: @Ben He gave me the wrong addresses! I should have known!

Comment: was the address 0x499602D2?

Comment: @user2242700 Glad I could help. Could you also accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it?

Comment: Don't worry, I plan to. I just always leave a question open for at least a day before closing it, in case anyone else wants to offer assistance. I don't see myself choosing any other answer as accepted at this point, but it has garnered some extra useful tips in the past, from time to time.

Comment: This is another reason I always leave them open for a day: I've got one last problem now: it's rounding down to the nearest decimal, but I need it to do standard rounding (round up to 0.56 if it's .555 or higher, rather than rounding down to 0.55). Is there any way to do that with this code? I thought about asking another question about it, but any question I asked would just have to explain how all this is set up again.

Comment: @user2242700 You shouldn't post follow-up questions in the comments, especially if I've already satisfied your original question. The best thing you can do is ask another question. But to answer this question anyway, [streams already do this by default](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). Where are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I'll post a separate question next time. The behavior I'm describing is what I'm seeing, but maybe it's because the float contains the result of a float divided by an int? I've verified that the float contains the value 0.555, but when displaying it as described here, it prints out 0.55 when I need it to display 0.56

Comment: @user2242700 In my last comment I meant to link you to [this post](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5700874a32f008b4) where the stream correctly rounds up. Can you give me a code example that shows what you are describing?

Comment: You're right, it is doing that for me, but for some reason, this particular variable is not being displayed correctly for some reason. The code is a bit complex at this point, so I'll try to isolate the problem and then post another question once I've figured out what's going on. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iomanip` library:

```
 os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::showpoint << rhs.price;
```

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class a
{
   public:
   double b;
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const a& rhs);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const a& rhs)
{
    os << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << rhs.b;
}

int main() {
     a n1;
     n1.b = 2.34567;
     cout << "Your num: " << n1 << std::endl;
     n1.b = 123.399999;
     cout << "Your num: " << n1 << std::endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

**output**

```
Your num: 2.35
Your num: 123.40
```

So this should definitely work if you are using c++.

Comment: What about the floatfield? Using it this way, numbers are still rounded down to one decimal place if the second decimal is a zero. Also, when I tested this, it still changed the stream permanently which is not what I want.

Comment: @user2242700 it shouldn't do, look at this example, when set to 9 it automatically pads with 0: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it shouldn't. I'm using GNU C++, not sure why it's doing that. When I set precision to 2 it outputs 0.1 but when I set it to 3 it outputs 0.101. So I guess I have to use some method to change the floatfield somehow like I was doing.

Comment: Also, this was a simplified example. I have to output multiple decimal values to two places from the same object, so it would be redundant to keep putting `setprecision` after each `<<`

Comment: I have edited the post to fix what your first comment, as for the second, i gues the other guys answer handles it?